# C mount function fails while similar command line mount succeeds

Tags: c, linux, filesystems, mount, nfs

When I try to mount directory, 'test_mount' through command line, the operation succeeds:

```
 mount -t nfs4 remote_server_ip:/ local_dir
```

but am unable to mount the same directory programmatically:

```
int ret_val = mount("remote_server_ip:/", "local_dir", "nfs4", MS_SYNCHRONOUS, "");
if (ret_val < 0) {
    perror("Mount failed");
    return 1;
}
```

This C function fails with `Mount failed: Invalid argument`. How can I programmatically mount the target directory? I'm running the executable with super user permissions.

Platform:

```
 Linux ip-10-1-19-46 3.10.42-52.145.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Jun 10 23:46:43 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: the solution is in this duplicate:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28350912/nfs-mount-system-call-in-linux

Answer (score 2):

It should be:

```
int ret_val = mount("remote_server_ip:/", "local_dir", "nfs4", MS_SYNCHRONOUS, NULL);
```

Instead of:

```
int ret_val = mount("remote_server_ip:/", "local_dir", "nfs4", MS_SYNCHRONOUS, "");
```

NULL and "" is different. "" is just means empty string. An empty string is not NULL.

Also, check for a valid filesystemtype argument value in /proc/filesystems

Comment: I agree, and have tried it already but unfortunately, this didn't work either.

Comment: Run this command for a valid filesystem arguments on your system
$ cat /proc/filesystems

Answer (score 1):

If you run `strace` on that `mount` command (with no options), you will see that it runs:

```
mount("remote_server_ip:/", "local_dir", "nfs4", MS_MGC_VAL, NULL)
```

So the fifth argument of `mount` should be `NULL` if you do not want to pass any options.