# NFS mount System Call in linux

Tags: embedded-linux, mount, nfs

I am trying to mount a source directory from nfs server to a destination directory in embedded board having linux. The following command works perfectly as expected in shell prompt in the board.

```
mount -t nfs -o nolock 10.126.62.45:/vol/home/avinoba/Sky /mnt
```

What is the equivalent system call to be used in program for the command above?
I tried the below call but the mount failed with "Invalid Argument"

```
if(mount("10.126.62.45:/vol/home/avinoba/Sky","/mnt","nfs",MS_MGC_VAL,"nolock") == -1)
{
     printf("ERROR: mount failed: %s \n",strerror(errno));
}
```

Please suggest what is the solution for it.

Thanks

Comment: You could have `strace`-ed the `mount` command to find the exact syscalls it is doing

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I'm quite surprised here knowing that how this is not covered by any man page regarding NFS mounts. Diving into the kernel code, in the function **nfs_validate_text_mount_data**, the function **nfs_parse_mount_options** is responsible for parsing the multiple comma separated options passed as the fifth argument in the **mount** system call.

```
struct sockaddr *sap = (struct sockaddr *)&args->nfs_server.address;

if (nfs_parse_mount_options((char *)options, args) == 0)
    return -EINVAL;

if (!nfs_verify_server_address(sap))
    goto out_no_address;
```

In the above code block, the last if statement checks whether the nfs server address and socket family is defined to valid values. If they are not updated within **nfs_parse_mount_options**, mount would end up returning invalid parameter.

If the implementation of **nfs_parse_mount_options** is walked through, it can be seen that, only for the case **Opt_addr**, the nfs server address and the socket family is updated by parsing the *options* argument.

```
case Opt_addr:
    string = match_strdup(args);
    if (string == NULL)
        goto out_nomem;
    mnt->nfs_server.addrlen =
        rpc_pton(mnt->net, string, strlen(string),
            (struct sockaddr *)
            &mnt->nfs_server.address,
            sizeof(mnt->nfs_server.address));
    kfree(string);
    if (mnt->nfs_server.addrlen == 0)
        goto out_invalid_address;
    break;
```

The case *Opt_addr* corresponds to the option *"addr=nfs server ip"*. So for the system call to work, defining this option is a **must**. As far as I have searched, this is completely missing from all the man pages which describes nfs mounts.

So now considering the problem statement, please try by changing to the below code

```
if(mount(":/vol/home/avinoba/Sky","/mnt","nfs",0,"nolock,addr=10.126.62.45") == -1)
{
     printf("ERROR: mount failed: %s \n",strerror(errno));
}
```

> Also note that when the *addr* option is put in the argument, the ip address in front of the nfs server path becomes optional. However the ':' is must,as this acts as the delimiter to parse the nfs server path.

Comment: **That really helped.. It is working as expected now.. It seems the man page of mount(2) needs an update or else someone has to look to the kernel source code as you did. Thanks Abhijit.**

Comment: this fails when addr is hotname any idea how to avoid the issue for hostname/fqdn?

Answer (score 0):

MS_MGC_VAL should be in the top 16 bits if needed, not the bottom. If your kernel version is > 2.4, you don't need it at all.

Comment: yes. you are correct. I dint find any suitable mountflag. Tried passing 0, but dint help any. kernel version is 2.6

Answer (score 0):

It solved by the following call for me now.

```
if(system("mount -t nfs -o nolock 10.126.62.45:/vol/home/avinoba/Sky /mnt")==-1);
{
     printf("ERROR: mount failed \n");
}
```

*But still searching for the answer with mount() call as it accepts 'filesystemtype' argument as "nfs".*